# Why is Firefox blocking me from this website as a possible "security risk"?

Tags: firefox, security

I clicked on a link on a website for an article (either on the same website or on another website) which I believe was probably harmless. Firefox took me to a screen with a security warning and asked me if I wished to "accept the risk" and proceed anyway. I clicked "accept/proceed" and was taken to another screen with the following message:

**We're sorry, you are not allowed to proceed**

**Your request looks suspiciously similar to automated requests from spam posting software or it has been denied by a security policy configured by the website administrator.**

**If you believe you should be able to perform this request, please let us know.**

**RID: JGAAIZFBTC364XEO8Y2CSWP7**

The webpage containing the link is https://www.antonysutton.com/

The link on that page which triggers the warning is the one for the Eulogy by Alan Stang (which I have read previously and contains no "risk" content).

The other links on the website do not trigger security warnings. I doubt that this website would have any links to actual bad websites. There is nothing bad about the content of the linked article.

Below is a screenshot of the page displaying the above message.

[image]

Comment: "If you believe you should be able to perform this request, please let us know." you need to act upon this request if it is false. It is not Ubuntu that is doing this but the owner of THAT server.

Comment: etherzone.com works well for me and has a valid certificate. Are you behind a firewall / proxy? E.g. in a company, school or something like that?

Comment: @pLumo I am able to go to etherzone website also but not that particular page, with that particular article. I am browsing from my desktop at home, on my own internet connection.

Comment: @Rinzwind Do you mean the server for the antonysutton.com site? It seemed to me that Firefox was doing it, though I can't recreate the original page which I was sent to before the one in the screenshot, to check on that. If I try the link again, I am sent straight to that page.

Comment: The first page where you had to "Accept the risk" may well have been Firefox, but the page you're showing here is generated by the website. Some sites block certain connections to protect themselves, like the page says. Are you using a VPN or Tor by any chance?

Comment: Those type of box errors usually pop up due to an IP address being flagged by website maybe in error.  The firefox warning could have been caused by bad ads on site.

Comment: @Allan fmozilla/firefox shows that when the site itself issues a warning. The 2nd one is actually from that site. What might be it is that you are using an URL they do not want you to use (it might be one that is activated from their site when you click a link).

Comment: @Sebastian No, not VPN or Tor. Just the www.

Comment: @Allan the warning from Firefox is just that - a warning. It didn't block you from accessing the website. You can seem from the HTTPS icon (a padlock with a yellow warning sign on it) that the website is not correctly using HTTPS (it's probably loading some script or image over HTTP). The message in the screenshot is from the site, and not from Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL that you find in the first site has two problems:

1. It points to a site named `www.etherzone.com` that resolves to  `167.71.126.142`. This address is also the address for just `etherzone.com`. The site admins use this to make their site reachable using either name. Unfortunately, the SSL certificate used for HTTPS is only valid for `etherzone.com`, so your Firefox warns you that the site may not be the one your think since it using a certificate meant for another site (the admins should have used a certificate usable for both names). This is not a problem on your end.
2. It corresponds to a resource named `2002/stang062702.shtml`. The *We're sorry, you are not allowed to proceed"* warning happens because the site is configured to specifically reject requests for `.shtml` URLs. It considers that legitimate users have no business getting these URLs. This isn't a problem on your end either, you are just using an obsolete URL.

The root cause of all this is that your starting page on `www.antonysutton.com` hasn't been updated for a long while, half the URLs on that page no longer work...

Comment: Can you please explain "trawling" and what it has to do with shtml? Is being paranoid a security risk? It would seem that Firefox is paranoid in assuming so. I have no trouble navigating to the paranoid website, only to that article, which is based not on paranoia, but documented, historical research. I can navigate to that link in your comment to that same article at the same website but on a different page.

Comment: See edited answer.

Comment: That makes sense and it also seems to be the consensus here that it is an issue with the website.

Comment: @Allan It's not *just* the "consensus", it's a *fact*. That '[HTTP 403 forbidden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403)' page is certainly a server-side message.